# Set MySQL option to restore MySQL server after deleting ibdata1

Tags: mysql

ON an Ubuntu Server 12.10 machine, I had attempted to delete the `ibdata1` file before reading [Rolando's explanation about how exactly to do so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40730/how-can-innodb-ibdata1-file-grows-by-5x-even-with-innodb-file-per-table-set). Specifically, I had not set `innodb_fast_shutdown = 0` before shutting MySQL down.

**How might I start MySQL, now that `ibdata1` has been deleted but `innodb_fast_shutdown` had not been set?**

I have backups of all the databases, but I cannot reinstall MySQL since the Ubuntu version is no longer supported. I cannot update Ubuntu to a supported version due to an accessibility issue in the current versions, nor can I downgrade to 12.04 LTS (still supported) since Ubuntu was never designed to be downgradable and some applications that I need won't run well on that older version if I do a complete reinstall as they depend on a string of dependencies not in 12.04 but in 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got a mysqldump export (.sql) of your databases, you do not need to have stopped mysql in any special way.

1. Make sure mysql is down

   ```
   pgrep mysqld
   (no output)
   ```
2. Delete everything on your datadir (by default, `/var/lib/mysql`)

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/mysql.bak && sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/* /tmp/mysql.bak
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   sudo mysql_install_db
   ```
4. Change the permissions od your datadir to the user mysql:

   ```
   sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
   ```
5. Start mysql:

   ```
   sudo service mysql start
   ```
6. Import your databases back:

   ```
   mysql -u root < your_dump.sql
   ```

You will have your databases back on a fresh installation of mysql, with a just created ibdata1.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I cannot reinstall MySQL because the OS is no longer supported. I tried that! I also mention why upgrading or downgrading the OS version is not feasible.

Comment: I am not suggesting you to reinstall mysql. I am suggesting you to run mysql_install_db, which resets the database contents without reinstalling any packages. Have you tried running that?

Comment: Thank you. I've bitten the bullet and installed an older version of the OS (Ubuntu 12.04). Thank you, I have learned much from this post.