# troubleshoot high value for mysql innodb pages written per second

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona-server

Our database is writting about 600 pages a second to its innodb buffer pools.

Usually this value is about 10 pages/sec, so the server is experiencing a very high IO utilization, around 50%.

Is there a way to troubleshoot why this is happening?

We are using percona 5.6.

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 105495134208; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 241200
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 16033996240     (1631980888 + 14402015352)
    Page hash           12750664 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    409029916   (407996944 + 1032972)
    File system         868440  (812272 + 56168)
    Lock system         316316440   (254997976 + 61318464)
    Recovery system     0   (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 1032972
Buffer pool size        6291448
Buffer pool size, bytes 103079084032
Free buffers            8183
Database pages          5400515
Old database pages      1993390
Modified db pages       185610
Pending reads 11
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 121, single page 0
Pages made young 47418283, not young 507790298
45.31 youngs/s, 20945.57 non-youngs/s
Pages read 9739157, created 2756858, written 212704492
36.69 reads/s, 15.94 creates/s, 539.34 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 7 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 5400515, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[222600]:cur[5776], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]



mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool%';
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                                            |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status          | Buffer pool(s) dump completed                    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status          | not started                                      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data           | 5400241                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data           | 88477548544                                      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty          | 169808                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty          | 2782134272                                       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed        | 213092827                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_LRU_flushed    | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free           | 8195                                             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young | 524456578                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young     | 47454214                                         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc           | 883012                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old            | 1993284                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total          | 6291448                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd       | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead           | 2432822                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests        | 8317257183491                                    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                | 6705654                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free            | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests       | 7090645000                                       |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%' ; 
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                             | Value                  |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                  | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm              | 10                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index                | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions     | 1                      |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay           | 150000                 |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size           | 8388608                |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval             | 5                      |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock                | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_trx_level                      | 0                      |
| innodb_autoextend_increment               | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                  | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown       | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename               | ib_buffer_pool         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances              | 8                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort             | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup        | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_populate               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                   | 103079215104           |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size             | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                   | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                 | innodb                 |
| innodb_checksums                          | ON                     |
| innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor             | high_checkpoint        |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled              | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                 | 0                      |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct  | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                  | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max            | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets                | 5000                   |
| innodb_corrupt_table_action               | assert                 |
| innodb_data_file_path                     | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                      |                        |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache            | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                        | ON                     |
| innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm          | backoff                |
| innodb_fake_changes                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                      | 1                      |
| innodb_file_format                        | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_format_check                  | ON                     |
| innodb_file_format_max                    | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_per_table                     | ON                     |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout               | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                       | O_DIRECT               |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                    | 1                      |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                 | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted               | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                     | 0                      |
| innodb_foreground_preflush                | exponential_backoff    |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                       |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                      | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print               | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                 | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                  | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                  | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize               | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit              | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table           |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                 | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size                | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table             |                        |
| innodb_io_capacity                        | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                    | 2000                   |
| innodb_kill_idle_transaction              | 0                      |
| innodb_large_prefix                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                  | 50                     |
| innodb_locking_fake_changes               | ON                     |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog            | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_arch_dir                       | ./                     |
| innodb_log_arch_expire_sec                | 0                      |
| innodb_log_archive                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_block_size                     | 512                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                    | 8388608                |
| innodb_log_checksum_algorithm             | innodb                 |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages               | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                      | 536870912              |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                 | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                 | ./                     |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                     | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_bitmap_file_size               | 104857600              |
| innodb_max_changed_pages                  | 1000000                |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                | 75                     |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm            | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                      | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay                | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups                | 1                      |
| innodb_monitor_disable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                      |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                  |                        |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                     | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                    | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size          | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                         | 2048                   |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only             | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_size                          | 16384                  |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks                | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                   | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                      | 1                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold               | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                    | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                          | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                  | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                  | 128                    |
| innodb_sched_priority_cleaner             | 19                     |
| innodb_show_locks_held                    | 10                     |
| innodb_show_verbose_locks                 | 0                      |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                   | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                    | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_method                       | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                   | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages      | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                 | 8                      |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages       | 8                      |
| innodb_strict_mode                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_support_xa                         | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                    | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                    | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                        | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                 | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                 | 10000                  |
| innodb_track_changed_pages                | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_directory                     | .                      |
| innodb_undo_logs                          | 128                    |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                   | 0                      |
| innodb_use_atomic_writes                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON                     |
| innodb_use_native_aio                     | ON                     |
| innodb_use_sys_malloc                     | ON                     |
| innodb_version                            | 5.6.14-rel62.0         |
| innodb_write_io_threads                   | 4                      |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
139 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

New relic showing the number of dirty pages: [image: dirty pages]

Looks like the number of dirty pages increased a lot, but it's still not too big of a percentage of dirty pages.

Thank you

Comment: Please run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'` and post that output into your question.

Answer (score 2):

From your status lists, here is what I see

- 96GB Buffer Pool
- Buffer is 85.8345% Full (88477548544 / 1030792151040);
- Dirty Pages

  - 2.699% of the whole buffer pool (2782134272 / 103079215104)
  - 3.1445% of the data in the buffer pool (2782134272 / 88477548544);

If there are so little dirty pages, why all the extra write activity ?

First, look at InnoDB's Architecture (from Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Look at the Buffer Pool in the Upper Left Corner

InnoDB needs [up to 25% for the Buffer Pool to handle changes to non-unique indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_change_buffer_max_size). This is handled in what is know as the "Insert Buffer". You have 2 opposing forces

- Your current setting (innodb_change_buffer_max_size=25)
- You are using 85% of the Buffer Pool, leaving 15% for the Insert Buffer

Your InnoDB Buffer Pool has now become a rope in a tug-of-war between index changes and data you are requesting/writing. This happens in a heavy write situation. This is what you are experiencing now. Consequently, the physical writes are occurring in the system tablespace (ibdata1) in the Insert Buffer section.

You are also beating one of the Undo Logs because all the rows in the DELETE have MVCC data piling up in it (just one Undo Log). If you go to the OS, and run `ls -l ibdata1`, it should be growing steadily right now (See my old post [How can Innodb ibdata1 file grows by 5X even with innodb_file_per_table set?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40730/how-can-innodb-ibdata1-file-grows-by-5x-even-with-innodb-file-per-table-set/40734#40734))

Going forward, you could do one of the following:

- dynamically adjust the [innodb_change_buffer_max_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_change_buffer_max_size) to a different number before such heavy writes.
- Do your `DELETE` query in chunks rather than a monolithic `DELETE`

Comment: Thank you. Yeah ibdata1 is growing a lot, it's 22GB now. If I kill this query would it stop the io or would it continue doing this? Thank for your explanation.

Comment: If you kill the DELETE, `ibdata1` should stop growing, but you have a big rollback to do.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it is a non-problem.  The buffer_pool waits until 90% (that's tunable) of it is filled with "dirty" blocks before it gets serious about flushing them to disk.  Dirty pages come from writes (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/etc).  I am unfamiliar with whether there will be a spike like you see.  (There used to be a *serious* spike, before Percona fixed it; but that was long before 5.6.)

Did you recently do a big UPDATE or something?

Your buffer_pool is 100GB?  I assume you have at least 128GB of RAM?

What was the Uptime when that STATUS list was dumped?

Are you seeing any other symptoms of trouble, such as slow queries?  If some slow query, let's look at it (plus `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`).

If you would like to provide `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`, plus RAM size, I will run some calculations for you.

Comment: Hi. Yes, there is a big DELETE statement running for 3 hours now. The delete statement started a few minutes before I saw high IO. So I think this could be the case? the percentage of dirty pages is nowhere near 75%, which is our value for innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct. 
Yes we have 128gb ram and uptime of a 462 days. This would explain it? Thanks

Comment: Added a chart with the number of dirty pages over time. This delete query started at 15:19

Comment: DELETEs do need to modify 16KB blocks (the unit of I/O in the buffer pool).  For suggestions on big deletes, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig .

Comment: In a huge DELETE, the buffer_pool will initially be able to absorb the activity.  But, sooner or later, the number of dirty pages will trigger a background thread to flush the pages.  The furious flushing may continue long after the DELETE terminates.  Also, there will be a lot of undo log activity.  If the amount to delete is bigger than innodb_log_file_size, the process may slow down due to needing to save "undo" information in a more complicated way.