# Huge /mysql/ folder size - about 289gb

Tags: mysql

The site had 504 errors, and as I found it was due to lack of memory. The site itself weighs 54GB, and the disk space is 500GB.

[image]

I found that the `/var/lib/mysql/` folder weighs as much as 289GB. As I understand it, it is difficult to call the norm.

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: What is in the directory? (Or rather, what is in the directory that is more than say 100 MB per file?)

Comment: From the strange, it is the set of files `{site}-bin.006029`. (006029, 006030, 006031) - different combinations of numbers

Comment: Those are binary logs. See my answer here for an explanation of what those logs are for, and how to manage them: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/320454/2703

Comment: @BillKarwin How to reduce the number of generated binlogs. They are created every 5-7 minutes for 1 GB

Comment: Please provide `du mysql` (when sitting above that directory).  Bill suspects it is binlogs in the directory.  Depending on max_binlog_size, each file might be 1GB or 100MB.  Or maybe some subdirectory (aka DATABASE) is huge.  `du` will tell us which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> How to reduce the number of generated binlogs. They are created every 5-7 minutes for 1 GB

Binary logs are produced on the source instance relative to the rate of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE you execute. The more writes to your database, the faster binary logs accumulate.

**First:** Ask yourself if you actually need the binary logs at all. If you disable writes to the binary log, this would of course eliminate them by 100%.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_log-bin

> To disable binary logging, you can specify the `--skip-log-bin` or `--disable-log-bin` option at startup. If either of these options is specified and `--log-bin` is also specified, the option specified later takes precedence. When binary logging is disabled, the `log_bin` system variable is set to `OFF`.

In MySQL 5.x, disabling it is is done differently: remove (or at least comment out) the `log_bin` variable in your my.cnf and restart the MySQL Server.

**Second:** If you decide you do need the binary logs, you could reduce the size by using `binlog_format=STATEMENT` or `binlog_format=MIXED`. There are advantages to the ROW based binary log format, and I prefer it when it's possible. But this log format often causes the logs to be larger.

**Third:** if you do need the binlogs to be in ROW format, you could use `binlog_row_image=MINIMAL` which means to omit columns that aren't changing from each logged event for an UPDATE or DELETE event. All columns are still needed in the log for INSERT events.

**Fourth:** Why are you writing to the database so much? Could your application be redesigned to make some of the updates in-memory only in cache? That way only a fraction of the data changes would be committed to the database, and the rate of binary log growth would be lower.

**Fifth:** If you can't make any of the other changes, then increase the size of your storage volume, until it accommodates the needs of your binary logs. If you've got a lot of traffic you do need the infrastructure resources to support it.